# How can I kill a program that might not exist from Perl on Win32?

Tags: perl, winapi

I'm looking for a way to make Perl kill all firefox.exe processes on Win32, and not give an error if no process exists. I'm currently using:

```
system('taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe');
```

which throws up a big "ERROR: No such process found", when firefox wasn't present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to suppress all output including errors, try this:

```
system('taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe >nul 2>&1');
```

You can see more information about command redirection and pipes here:

http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: yeah, just change the `firefox.exe` to `iexplore.exe`

Answer (score 3):

```
`taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe 2>&1`
```

Comment: This creates a (possibly empty) file called `1` in the current directory.

Comment: slight typo here.  you have the right idea, but if you just want to redirect error output, it should be `2>nul` instead of `2>1`

Comment: Perhaps tster intended to write `2>&1`.

Answer (score 3):

without calling taskkill, you can use Perl modules, eg [Win32::Process::List](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-Process-List/List.pm), [win32::Process::Kill](http://search.cpan.org/~rootkwok/Win32-Process-Kill-2.64/lib/Win32/Process/Kill.pm)

See also [perldoc -f kill](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html)