# Check if process is running and kill it

Tags: perl

I am using perl version 5.8.4.

I am working with a program called JMP. Before opening the program I want to use perl to check if a process of the program is already running. If it is running, I want to close it.

Comment: see this might help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273636/check-if-program-is-running-and-run-it-if-not-in-perl

Comment: $exists = kill 0, 1525;
print "Process is running\n" if ( $exists ); from this u can also check

Comment: what does it mean  0,1525? how it refers to to the specific process?

Comment: What operating system? How, exactly, does your perl script *start* JMP?

Comment: windows. my only problem is to find out if the possess in running and if so, the shut it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REWORK: (Idk how I get here, I'm just lost)

This only works in windows cause is a shell execute (Taskkill).

```
system('taskkill /F /IM ImageName.exe >nul 2>&1');
```

Possible duplicate of:

[How can I kill a program that might not exist from Perl on Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052416/how-can-i-kill-a-program-that-might-not-exist-from-perl-on-win32)

perl > system documentation:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Taskkill documentation:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true

About syntax redirection ( Based in a awnser from [How can I kill a program that might not exist from Perl on Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052416/how-can-i-kill-a-program-that-might-not-exist-from-perl-on-win32) ):

http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add this:

```
use autodie 'system';
system('killall', '-q', 'JMP');
```

or

```
use autodie 'system';
system('pkill', 'JMP');
```

If you want to handle error checking yourself instead of using autodie, it would look like

```
die "Can't launch killall: $!\n"                 if $? < 0;
die "killall killed by signal ".($? & 0x7F)."\n" if $? & 0x7F;
die "killall exited with error ".($? >> 8)."\n"  if $? >> 8;
```

Comment: You might want to add a note on how you can check the exit code to do other things.

Comment: Turns out OP is using Windows anyway and neglected to tell us. :D

Comment: I noticed, but he already has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using the helpful input I've got from others on this question, rewriting the answer to be more suitable for the question at hand.

It checks if the process is running, giving you the ability to do more than kill it (print output to console, kill its sub processes if required, etc.), runs `killall` **only** if the program is running, and then starts `jmp`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

# Read all script-name processes
open PROS, "ps -ef| grep jmp |";

# Iterate the processes
while ($line = <PROS>){
    # If we match the process, kill all instances
    unless ($line =~ m/grep/){
        system 'killall jmp';
        last;
    }
}

# Finished with the processes
close PROS;

# Start jmp
exec 'nohup /path/to/jmp &';
```

If you're using Windows, you'll want to look into `taskkill` instead of `killall`.

Comment: i recieve an error: 'ps' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Vera So you're using Windows? Would have been useful to put in the question.